# Copy-Paste a figure from MS Office to html

Tags: html, ms-office, powerpoint, contenteditable, copy-paste

When you copy a figure in MS powerpoint (e.g. a square or an arrow), it is possible to paste it in other microsoft products such as MS Word or MS Outlook.

Is it possible to make a web page that can also do that?

I have tried to paste from powerpoint to a contenteditable div or to a textarea, but nothing happens.

I guess it will not work out-of-the box, but is there anyway to access to the information in the copy-paste buffer somehow, even if they are in any type of microsoft format?

Answer (score 1):

You can listen to the 'paste' event, and get an image blob form the ClipboardEvent object.
Code sample:

```
document.addEventListener('paste', handleClipBoard);
function handleClipBoard(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(ev.clipboardData.items, function(item) {
    if (item.kind === 'string') {
      item.getAsString(function(content) {
          ev.target.innerHTML += content;
      });
    } else if(item.kind === 'file') {
      var blob = item.getAsFile();
      console.dir(blob);
      var img = document.createElement('img');
      img.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      ev.target.appendChild(img);
    }
  });
}
```

The ClipboardEvent API is specified here: http://www.w3.org/TR/clipboard-apis
However, this API is quite new and only chrome has full support for now.

You will note that content in clipboard may be pasted multiple times, this is because data in clipboard can take different format simultaneously. You can filter them by item.type property.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy the raw data only then it is possible. As because Buffer stores only the character ASCII values not the style of the particular text. If you want that style also then use css file

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. If I copy-paste formatted text, it works out-of-the box. I am more interested in copying figures (e.g. square, arrow, image)

Answer (score 0):

Right click the figure, choose Save as Picture and save to PNG/JPG.
Then use an img tag in your html to reference the image.